# simple grammar question about transaction completed page

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say:
"An email with your order details has been sent to the email address you have provided us with. We will send you another email once your order will be complete." ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That seems alright, but a better way of wording it is:

> An email with your order **information** has been sent to the email address you **provided**. We will send you another email once your order **has been completed**.

(emphasis shows changes from original)